# Angular md-sidenav does not open inside of my codepen

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Trying to get my md-sidenav to open when I click the burger-icon but I can't get it working. I've tried checking for log messages and also creating a simple `sayHi` function that doesnt print anything to console but I'm not seeing any JS errors either. I'm working off a [codepen](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/sidenav) provided in the Angular-Material docs. Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/danielyaa5/pen/dGaEvO).

### HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="analysis" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')">

      <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Left</h1>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-content layout-padding="" ng-controller="LeftCtrl">
        <md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary" hide-gt-md="">
          Close Sidenav Left
        </md-button>
        <p hide-md="" show-gt-md="">
          This sidenav is locked open on your device. To go back to the default behavior,
          narrow your display.
        </p>
      </md-content>

    </md-sidenav>
  <div class="menubar">
    <div id="sidenav-open">
      <button ng-click="toggleLeft()"><md-icon>menu</md-icon></button>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown" id="file-btn">
      <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">File <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="view-ctrls-cntnr">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[0]}" ng-click="toggleView(0)">R-Theta</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[1]}" ng-click="toggleView(1)">Cartesian</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[2]}" ng-click="toggleView(2)">Longitudinal</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'active-view': active_views[3]}" ng-click="">Console</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="views-cntnr">
    <div id="r1" class="view-row">
      <div id="v1" class="view">
        <div class="v-header">V1</div>
      </div>
      <div id="v2" class="view">V2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="r2" class="view-row">
      <div id="v3" class="view">V3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="r3" class="view-row">
      <div id="v4" class="view">Console</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-ctrl-cntnr">
    <div id="frame-num" class="frame-ctrl"># X</div>
    <div id="frame-range-cntnr" class="frame-ctrl">
      <input type="range">
    </div>
    <div id="footer-btns-cntnr">
      <button id="console-btn">Console</button>
      <button id="hotkey-btn" class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

### Angular

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log) {

  $scope.sayHi = function() {
    console.log('console hi');
    $log.debug('log hi');
  };

    $scope.toggleLeft = buildDelayedToggler('left');
    /**
     * Build handler to open/close a SideNav; when animation finishes
     * report completion in console
     */
    function buildDelayedToggler(navID) {
      return debounce(function() {
        $mdSidenav(navID)
          .toggle()
          .then(function() {
            $log.debug("toggle " + navID + " is done");
          });
      }, 200);
    }

    function buildToggler(navID) {
      return function() {
        $mdSidenav(navID)
          .toggle()
          .then(function() {
            $log.debug("toggle " + navID + " is done");
          });
      }
    }
  }).controller('LeftCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log) {
    $scope.close = function() {
      $mdSidenav('left').close()
        .then(function() {
          $log.debug("close LEFT is done");
        });

    };
  });
```

### CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.analysis {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}


/* MENUBAR */

.menubar {
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: hsl(0, 0%, 75%) solid 1px;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
}


/* VIEWS-CTRLS-CNTNR */

#view-ctrls-cntnr {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#view-ctrls-cntnr button {
  font-size: inherit;
}


/*view-ctrls-cntnr */


/* BURGER ICON */

#sidenav-open {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 34px;
}

#sidenav-open button {
  border: none;
}

#sidenav-open button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0392157);
}

/* burger icon */


/* FILE-BTN */

#file-btn {
  margin-left: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

#file-btn button {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100%;
}

#file-btn button:focus {
  background-color: white;
}

#file-btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0392157);
}


/* FILE-DROPDOWN */

#file-btn .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  z-index: 10;
  left: -34px;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}


/* file-btn */


/* menubar */


/* VIEWS */

#views-cntnr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* ROWS */


/* ROW 1 */

#r1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 4;
}

#r1 .view {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
}

#r1 .view:last-child {
  border-right: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
}


/* row 1 */


/* ROW 2 */

#r2 .view {
  border: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#r2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 3;
}


/* row 2 */


/* ROW 3 */

#r3 .view {
  border: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#r3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
}


/* row 3 */


/* rows */


/* views */


/* FOOTER CTRL */

#footer-ctrl-cntnr {
  display: flex;
}

.frame-ctrl {
  border: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.frame-ctrl:last-child {
  border-right: black 1px solid;
}

#frame-num {
  width: 50px;
}

#frame-range-cntnr {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 4px;
}


/* FOOTER BTNS */

#footer-btns-cntnr {
  border-left: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

#footer-btns-cntnr button {
  margin: 2px;
}

#console-btn {
  font-size: 8px;
}


/* footer ctrl */
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it wasn't working was that I forgot to add `ng-controller` tag to my html. No controller thus no scope. Whoops.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11277317)

Comment: No this is the answer to why it wasn't working. I'll make that more clear.